# Javascript: Check whether key exists in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var users = [
  { 'id': '1', 'coins': false },
  { 'id': '2', 'coins': false }
];

var a = _.every(users, function(p){
  if ('id' in p && 'coins' in p)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
});
console.log(a);
```

The function works to check in keys exists in an array of objects.
If one of the object doesn't exists "id" or "coins" , it return false.

Is there a better way to write thie snippet of code?
I felt quite clumsy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're in node.js, you know you already have `array.every()` so I don't see any reason for lodash here or for the `if/else`.  Why not this:

```
var users = [
  { 'id': '1', 'coins': false },
  { 'id': '2', 'coins': false }
];

var allValid = users.every(function(item) {
    return 'id' in item && 'coins' in item;
});
```

FYI, this code is assuming nobody has mysteriously added properties named `id` or `coins` to the Object.prototype (which seems like a safe assumption here).  If you wanted to protect against that, you could use `item.hasOwnProperty('id')` instead of `in`.

Comment: @RobG - I will add that caveat, but these are literals so `.hasOwnProperty()` does not seem necessary here.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for this explanation!

Answer (score 2):

At very least, replace:

```
if ('id' in p && 'coins' in p)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

With:

```
return 'id' in p && 'coins' in p;
```

Basically, ***never*** use a construct like:

```
if (x)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

`x` is already a boolean, or at least a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) / [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.

In case you need to be sure the returned value is a boolean, just force it to one:

```
return !!('id' in p && 'coins' in p);
```

---

Also, as mentioned in the other answer, lodash is redundant, here. You canuse JS's native `[every][3]`.
Replace:

```
_.every(users, function(p){
```

With:

```
users.every(function(p){
```

Comment: Well, `x` is not necessarily a boolean... It is in this particular case, but not always.

Comment: You don't need the `!!` here.  The `in` operator already returns a boolean.

Comment: @jfriend00: I just added that as an explanation that _always_ replacing an if statement like that can sometimes result in unexpected responses.

Comment: The [*in* relational operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-relational-operators) returns true/false, it's the comment in regard to the `if (x)` test that wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.has()`](https://lodash.com/docs#has) to check if an object property exists:

```
function checkValidity(array, listOfKeys) {
    return _.every(array, function (item) {
        return _.every(listOfKeys, function (key) {
            return _.has(item, key);
        });
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
checkValidity(users, ['id', 'coins']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [Array.prototype.some()][1] function:

```
 var users = [
  { 'id': '1', 'coins': false },
  { 'id': '2', 'coins': false }
];


    var result = users.some(e => e.hasOwnProperty('id') && e.hasOwnProperty('coins'));

    console.log("The array contains an object with a 'name' and 'quantity' property: " + result);
```